# my application not connecting with databse becouse the database is on the any other server but I have the ssh creadentials but getting error

Tags: mariadb

```
ssh javauser@238.34.23.23 "74H37D6BD89B2 -u admin -ps33d2d2 zyzwer" > dump.sql,
```

I am not able to dub the particular database ,please help in the resoving this part.

```
ssh des2ser@23.23.23.23.23 "423ds32sd23dw2 -u admin -pzsds@1231 sd_nsffsdfs" > dump.sql
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking and what problem you are having. Can you share exactly the commands you are issuing as well as the error you are getting. Also, better explain what you are trying to accomplish. What does "dub" mean?